# Is there a suitable Two wire interface / I2C reading writing library in Contiki OS for Atmega128 platform?

Tags: c, interrupt, interrupt-handling, contiki

I wish to read the EUI64 address from an AT24MAC602 memory chip interfaced to an Atmega128rfa1 MCU over the Two wire interface. I tried to modify the I2C master drivers which are available for other platforms to suit my need. However, I wasn't able to carry out these modifications successfully as the program stopped responding as soon as the slave address was written to the twi bus with Write flag set. I failed to uncover the underlying reasons for the same. 
As Contiki OS is quite popular, i thought someone might have already come up with contiki specific libraries for reading writing over TWI interface for Atmega128rfa1 MCU. If so, please provide pointers to the twi drivers or documentation for the same, or suggest factors that should be considered for developing such drivers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any luck finding/creating a driver for the TWI peripheral, you might consider emulating it by configuring the SDA/SCL pins as general I/O and then implementing the TWI protocol yourself. If you're just doing a one-time read of a chip ID then speed probably isn't a big concern, so this could work if you get desperate. Google should throw up a few examples of emulated TWI.